# Notify before suspend

Tags: suspend, notifications

`systemd-suspend.service` man page:

> Note that scripts or binaries dropped in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
>   are intended for local use only and should be considered hacks. If
>   applications want to be notified of system suspend/hibernation and
>   resume, there are much nicer interfaces available.

So what are some of these "nicer interfaces" that I can use to get notified before suspension? (would be nice if it is before n sec/min)

Comment: I'm not sure which ones they're referring to, but http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit is one of them...

Answer (score 0):

"Nicer interfaces" is probably referring to the Inhibitor Locks implemented in `systemd-logind.service`, which includes a logic to inhibit system shutdowns and sleep states.

From `man systemd-logind.service`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> systemd-logind is a system service that manages user logins. It is responsible for:
>
> - ...
> - Implementing a shutdown/sleep inhibition logic for applications
>
> ...
>
> For more information on the inhibition logic see the Inhibitor [Lock Developer Documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit).

Another solution that I can think of is to write a 
systemd service, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124212/writing-a-systemd-service-to-be-executed-at-resume) related question for example.