# How to react to laptop lid events?

Tags: linux, systemd, d-bus

I have a Fedora 26 Lenovo laptop, which means I have a little trackpoint nub for pointer motion as well as the trackpad. By default, the pointer motion is sluggish. So I have a job that sets some parameters in /sys/devices. I set them after reboot, but whenever I close and reopen my laptop lid, those parameters are reset. I want my parameters to remain unchanged, or at least be automatically correctable after the lid opens.

My question is: Is it possible to do what I want quickly? I don't want to have to dig into systemd. I'm looking for a 5-minute fix so I can get back to what I was doing.

The pointer to this article [Writing a systemd service to be executed at resume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124212/writing-a-systemd-service-to-be-executed-at-resume) includes an answer by mivk which answered the question for me. I will followup there with my solution.

Comment: If lid close/open = suspend/resume then see [Writing a systemd service to be executed at resume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124212)