# systemd, journalctl, and suspend/resume (sleep/wake): marked by default in the logs? Or how to add? And scripting around suspend/resume in general?

Tags: systemd, suspend, init-script, systemd-journald, journalctl

(
First of all, I'm not completely sure what the official terms are.
I *think* it's "suspend"/"resume",
with "sleep"/"wake" being synonyms
(and I'm not sure if there are any other common synonyms).

And there's other, related-but-different stuff, namely "hibernate",
which is much more rarely used because hardware support for it is trickier and often not worth trying to mess with (I believe?).

(There's also "suspend-to-ram". I'm less clear whether that's a synonym for plain "suspend", or for "hibernate", or what.)

However, it's only "sleep"/"wake" that I'm interested in here.
)

---

So I wanted to look back through my system's journal to see what's been happening right after I wake the system from sleep.

(I have a USB keyboard that seems to not be coming back properly until I unplug-and-replug it, and I *think* it's a software issue, and I'm trying to figure it out.)

However, I'm not confident that I'm consistently finding the correct spots in the system journal.

Someone told me to manually run
(before sleep):
`su root -c 'echo "Sleep started" > /dev/kmsg'`
(after sleep):
`su root -c 'echo "Sleep ended" > /dev/kmsg'`

Which seemed odd to me,
because I would've thought that *something* already logged to the journal by default would mark sleep/wake?

If so, what?

---

And if not, how *should* I add something to *automatically* log sleep/wake times?

And just in general,
how should I do scripting around sleep/wake?

eg, if I *did* want to take
`su root -c 'echo "Sleep started" > /dev/kmsg'`
and
`su root -c 'echo "Sleep ended" > /dev/kmsg'`
and make them automatically run before and after sleep respectively
(as close as possible to the last/first thing before/after that sleep)?

I found this file:
`/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`
should I be working with that?

(
Like, I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of an init-script,
but for wake/sleep rather than just boot/shutdown.
...
Although in the case of sleep, I note it's possible to just have a single script run,
with a command to sleep in the middle of the script,
and then, without needing to do anything else,
the rest of the script will continue running after you wake the computer back up.

Not sure whether that's the *right* way of doing things, but it's certainly in principle possible.
)

---

Also, I only just started using `journalctl` like a week ago honestly.

Before that, I only used `dmesg` occasionally (with the `--ctime`/`-T` flag)
-- just whenever I wanted to check if something had recently OOM'd or segfaulted or whatever.

However, `dmesg --ctime` has a longstanding bug
where it just counts seconds since boot,
and then naively turns that into a "human readable" timestamp,
but completely ignores sleep/wake
so the timestamps actually drift further and further back out of sync from the *actual* real time the longer have your computer running,
if you're sleeping it every night but not *rebooting*.

So do the timestamps for `journalctl` still have that bug,
or is that fixed?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know the terms? Then [systemd-sleep](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sleep.html) is the meta-service for supending and hibernating. Do you want to run services before/after suspending/resuming? Then have a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/619987/stop-systemd-service-before-suspend-start-again-after-resume) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124212/writing-a-systemd-service-to-be-executed-at-resume). Kindly try to ensure your question can be well followed and focuses on a specific problem.

Comment: @FelixJN The question is essentially: "**How do you handle logging and scripting related to sleep/wake with systemd?**" The rest is clarifying details. (For instance, if I accidentally used the wrong terms for "sleep"/"wake", I wanted to make that clear and clarify my *intended* meaning right-off-the-bat.)

Comment: The respective marker in the logs would be [`systemd-sleep`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841197/logs-of-ubuntu-going-into-sleep-and-waking-up) then - if I understand you correctly.